# Get event target from within Javascript module

Tags: javascript, dom-events, revealing-module-pattern

I'm using the revealing module pattern for the first time and gradually getting to grips with it.

In my html I have something like this:

```
<a href='#' onclick='myApp.doStuff'>Click here</a>
```

In Javascript I have:

```
var myApp = (function () {

    var doStuff = function() {
        //Get clicked element and modify it with jQuery?
    }

    return {
        doStuff: doStuff
    }

})();
```

How do I get the clicked element at the point indicated above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use jQuery methods, like alex23 said.
But you can also write in html:

```
<a href='#' onclick='myApp.doStuff(this)'>Click here</a>
```

and this for your javascript:

```
var myApp = (function () {

    var doStuff = function(elem) {
        //use the element here
    }

    return {
        doStuff: doStuff
    }

})();
```

**Update**
If you want to pass the event object, too, extend the call in onclick to:

```
onclick='myApp.doStuff(this, event)'
```

and the javascript to:

```
...
var doStuff = function(elem, event){
...
}
```

Comment: I prefer this answer because it clearly illustrates that you need to pass in the event object and how to do it.

Comment: Thx, but it is not the event object I pass there, it's the a-element itself. If you want to pass the event object too, write: onclick='myApp.doStuff(this,event)'. Then you can access the a-element and the event object.

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery event handling for that. Cross browser event handling is not a trivial matter in JavaScript.

Say you have:

```
<a id="someLink" ..etc>Click here</a>
$("#someLink").click(function(event) {
   $(this).html("I have been clicked");
});
```

Comment: Are you saying I shouldn't use `onclick` or are you saying I should use `$(this)`?